# Web scraping Ajax.requests with Python and BeautifulSoup - Seemingly random page numbers return blank

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a book reviews website with BeautifulSoup, where there are 10 pages of reviews with 30 reviews each. I can get 8 pages out of the 10, but pages 4 and 6 seemingly return blank scrapes.

Here is a simple demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import fnmatch
import os

url='https://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/1202.Freakonomics?amp;page=4'

result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

soup.prettify()
```

This returns blank. However, substituting the 4 or 6 with any other page from 1-10 will return the full scraped page.

I would appreciate any help with what might be going on here. Thanks

Comment: I can't seem to get a valid response from that url endpoint.

Comment: Forgive me I'm not up with html lingo. If you mean the normal url, it's: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1202.Freakonomics If you mean scraping, yeah that url returns nothing, however if you run the above code with url = https://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/1202.Freakonomics?amp;page=5 You do get data back. Hopefully that's what you meant.